# How to parse pojo into simple String json using Jackson 'fasterxml.jackson', in Camel without having full class name

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-camel

I'm using camel(that uses jackson to parse) & parsing my pojos in json, but I'm getting output json:

```
{"com.xyz.Demo":{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","fruits":
{"@serialization":"custom","unserializable-parents":"","list":{"default":
{"size":1},"int":1,"com.xyz.demo.Fruit":{"colour":"orange","timeStamp":"2020-
01-01T02:55:45Z"}}}}}
```

I want just class name, not with full package.
Also don't want: "@serialization":"custom","unserializable-parents":""

Respective classes:

```
public class Demo {
 private String key1 = null;
 private String key2 = null;
 private Fruits fruits = null;
}

public class Fruits extends ArrayList<Fruit> {
}

public class Fruit {
 private String colour = null;
 private String timeStamp = null;
}
```

Conversion in Camel route: .marshal().json()

Tried annotating model classes with @JsonRootName , didn't work.

Comment: try  `.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)`

Comment: @pvpkiran Ah, didn't work.

Comment: I solved it by using separate json serialiser in a processor, instead of using Camel's.